# I want to print a sequence of letters and concatenate it with an existing string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement where i need to add an alphabet A to Z sequentially to a string.
example :
OGCP223000 + A
OGCP223000 + B,etc

So that I get

OGCP223000A,OGCP223000B till OGCP223000Z, and start again every time I run the SP.
So one time I call the stored procedure I want A, and the next time I want B, and the time after that i want C, and so on
Please help

I used numbers by creating a sequence in SQL server, but could not for Alphabets

Comment: Which version(s) of SQL Server do you need to support? (`SELECT @@VERSION` as opposed to Help > About in SSMS.)

Comment: Sql Server 2016 (SP3-CU1-GDR)

Comment: So you should clarify that one time you call the stored procedure you want `A`, and the next time you want `B`, and the time after that you want `C`, and so on. Right now it reads ambiguously (and I spent time and effort on a solution that concatenates). Also make it clear whether each time you call the procedure you _store_ this string somewhere, and if they ever get deleted, what happens? If I create A, then B, then C, then delete C, should the next call create C or D?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `sequence` to produce a cycle of alphabetic values. Start with a sequence that cycles through values from `1` to `26`:

```
create sequence AlphaValue as Int MinValue 1 MaxValue 26 Cycle;
```

Then you can use `Char` to convert the returned value into the corresponding letter:

```
declare @Count as Int = 0;
declare @AlphaValue as Int;

while @Count < 30
  begin
  set @AlphaValue = next value for AlphaValue;
  select @Count as Count, @AlphaValue as AlphaValueInt,
    -- Convert the 1..26 value into the corresponding letter.
    Char( ASCII( 'A' ) + @AlphaValue - 1 ) as AlphaValueChar;
  set @Count += 1;
  end;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FxqZev6L).

Note that the usual warnings about sequences sometimes skipping values apply.

Comment: Thanks for this, but everytime I run this the next alphabet is skipping three. For instance, if it is A the first time, it is E the next time when the query is executed

Comment: Thank you, was able to figure it out.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you, was able to figure it out,  with your help of course.. Please see the code below, This will print A to Z individually every time I run this block of code

Declare @Alphabet TABLE (Alpha1 VARCHAR(1), Alphaint VARCHAR(2), Count1 INT)

Declare @Count as Int = 0;

Declare @AlphaValue as Int;

while @Count < 30

begin

set @AlphaValue = next value for AlphaValue;

INSERT @Alphabet (Count1, Alphaint, Alpha1)

select @Count as Count, @AlphaValue as AlphaValueInt,
-- Convert the 1..26 value into the corresponding letter.
Char( ASCII( 'A' ) + @AlphaValue - 1 ) as AlphaValueChar;
set @Count += 1;

end;

Select Alpha1 from @Alphabet where Count1=0

Comment: How does this code work in a stored procedure to keep track of which letter is _next_? Since it effectively doesn't use a sequence it has no memory of what letter was returned last. It could be simplified to use `Substring( 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', @Count + 1, 1 )`.